# How to achieve no recoil script based on c++ to do additional movements of my mouse

Tags: c++, mouse

I just picked up scripting and I'm bit confused at scripting and have no idea what I'm doing. Made a script to do basic mousemovements on C++ I want it to make adjustments. So what I'm trying to achieve here is, in this game my gun's recoil goes to up and to the left, but then halfway into spray it goes to the right while increasing the intensity of the recoil. I want the script to initially be able to pull the mouse down and to the right, and then (when the guns recoil starts to go in the other direction) go to the left. Is this achievable with my code? With my current code it just jitters into a square.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

bool keyDown(int vcode)
{
    return GetAsyncKeyState(vcode) & ~32767;
}

int main(void)
{
    bool isOn = true;
    while (!keyDown(121))
    {
        if (keyDown(120))
        {
            isOn = !isOn;
            Sleep(200);
        }

        if (keyDown(1) && isOn)
        {
            Sleep(25);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, 0, 10, 0, 0);
            Sleep(25);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, -10, -0, 0, 0);
            Sleep(25);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, 10, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        Sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to add a timer in to the X and Y cordinates. Possibly to negate a certain type of recoil that has a pattern of zigzag. With the below code it all performs at once creating a square like mouse movement hence I need to add timers in between the cordinates maybe?

I want the script to not only move down and slightly to the left

```
            Sleep(25);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, 0, 10, 0, 0);
            Sleep(25);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, -10, -0, 0, 0);
```

but I want to be able to specify that after a certain amount of time, I then want the script to move in a different direction that again, I can specify.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: SO is not a programming/Homework service

Comment: Its not a homework. Its a no recoil script for first person shooter games.

Comment: recoil is not implemented as mouse movements but animation of the camera angles, as part of the frame loop

Comment: aren't ingame recoils based on how many pixel units moved by the mouse?

Comment: in your implementation the image freezes, no object movement because you **sleep**, so my suggestion is a lot better, objects move during recoil

Comment: how do you implement jump?

Comment: whats your suggestion?

Comment: I'm not writing any line of code, read my comment and implement that if you like the idea

Comment: You dont have to code me. A clue would be nice.. thanks in advance